# What scriptures describe Vishnu's Mukta-damodara-bandana?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, vaikuntha

As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2756/36), the Sri Vaishnava sect (of which I am a member) places great importance on the Divya Desams, the 108 sacred places of Vishnu which are mentioned in the poems of the Alwars. Now two of the Divya Desams are not even on Earth! As I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9917/36), there is Thiruparkadal, Vishnu's ocean of milk, and then there is Paramapadam, the abode of Para Vasudeva or the supreme Vishnu as well as the destination of those who have attained Moksha. (See my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6923/36) for more information on Para Vasudeva.)

[image]

In any case, here is how [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/D4hs) from the Yatindra Mata Dipika, a work by the 17th century Sri Vaishnava Acharya Srinivasa Dasa, describes Para Vasudeva's appearance:

> Now It (Soul) approaches nearer the (Divine) Seat, where it finds the throne thereon, Dharma (etc.) made, the Lotus over it, and Ananta over again.  On the sides stand Vimala, etc., with fans (waving) in their hands, serving God (Bhagavan); Who is installed there with His (Queens) Shri, Bhu and Nila; Wo Is bedecked with the Divine Weapons: Conch, Discus etc.; Who is blazing with the countless Divine Ornaments: the Crown, the Diadem; and, for the head, ears, neck, breast, arms, wrists, waist and ankles, such (jewels) as Cudavatarhsa, Makara-kundala, Graiveyaka-hara, Keyura, Kataka, Shri-vatsa, Kaustubha, **Mukta-damodara-bandhana**, Pitambara, Kanchiguna, Nupura etc.; and Who is the boundless Ocean of Graces.

Now some of these attributes are recognizable: the Makara Kundalas are Vishnu's shark-shaped earrings, the Shrivatsa is the tuft of hair on Vishnu's chest where Lakshmi resides, and the Kaustubha is the gem Vishnu wears around his neck.  But my question is, what is the Mukta-damodara-bandhana?

Now Mukta means liberated soul, i.e. a soul which has attained Moksha.  Damodara means one who has a rope tied around his waist.  And Bandhana means refers to tying something or someone up with a rope.  So is the the Mukta-damodara-bandana a rope used to keep liberated souls attached to Vishnu?

Now of course, Vishnu doesn't actually keep liberated souls attached to him by lassoing them with a rope.  Rather, they automatically remain attached to him; they perform devotional service to Vishnu out of a sheer outpouring of joy.  But does anyone know any scriptures which mention Vishnu carrying a Mukta-damodara-bandana?

Comment: Perhaps it is pointing towards the Bandhana on **Damodara's** udara. So a better question would be what is Mukta Damodara Bandhana, because your translation could be wrong.

Comment: Also it is Muktaa and not mukta - which points more to a sort of pearl waistlet for Vishnu. Muktaa Damodara Bandhana - a rope of pearls to fasten the waist.

Comment: @Surya Oh, that would be about 2000 times less interesting than what I was speculating. Anyway I'm changing the title of my question.

Comment: I'm unclear with accurate interpretation/meaning with Damodara

Comment: @Keshav Haha it does. And I do think there will be many scriptural references to his odyanam if that's what it means.

Comment: I'm thinking of Krsna and how Maa Yashoda binds Him to the mortar, and such a pastime is called damodara bandhana lila. Could this be what is isbeing referred to here? It is described in Padma Purana I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @Nitaidasa Yes, Krishna is called Damodara because Yashoda tied him up.  But that wouldn't explain the Muktaa part.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Mukta also means loose, so it can refer to a string that is bound loosely at the waist of Sri Narayana. Lord Krsna and Baladeva also have this string which fastens their pitambara and holds The Lord's flutes and horns etc. Perhaps it simply means the Brahmin thread? (which in essence is a loose string that binds the torso/stomach).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan what Surya says seems closest to me. the word 'Muktavali' appears in famous song 'Kasturi Tilakam' and is translated as 'Necklace'. here mukta I feel refers to loose chain of pearls;Damodar-Bandahana is used on account of this necklace being bound to waist.